# Error while creating hive table through Kylin build cube

Tags: hadoop, hive, kylin

HI I am trying to build a cube with Kylin, the data gets souced fine from sqoop but the next step for creating hive tables fails . Looking at the command being fired it looks weird as the create statement looks good to me .

I think the issue is with DOUBLE types as when I remove the same the create statement works fine . Can someone please help .

I am using the stack in AWS EMR, kylin 2.5 hive 2.3.0

The errors logs with commands as as below

Command

```
    hive -e "USE default;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS kylin_intermediate_fm_inv_holdings_8a1c33df_d12b_3609_13ee_39e169169368;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kylin_intermediate_fm_inv_holdings_8a1c33df_d12b_3609_13ee_39e169169368
(
HOLDINGS_STOCK_INVESTOR_ID string
,STOCK_INVESTORS_CHANNEL string
,STOCK_STOCK_ID string
,STOCK_DOMICILE string
,STOCK_STOCK_NM string
,STOCK_APPROACH string
,STOCK_STOCK_TYP string
,INVESTOR_ID string
,INVESTOR_NM string
,INVESTOR_DOMICILE_CNTRY string
,CLIENT_NM string
,INVESTOR_HOLDINGS_GROSS_ASSETS_USD double(22)
,INVESTOR_HOLDINGS_NET_ASSETS_USD double(22)
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://wfg1tst-models/kylin/kylin_metadata/kylin-4ae3b18b-831b-da66-eb8c-7318245c4448/kylin_intermediate_fm_inv_holdings_8a1c33df_d12b_3609_13ee_39e169169368';
ALTER TABLE kylin_intermediate_fm_inv_holdings_8a1c33df_d12b_3609_13ee_39e169169368 SET TBLPROPERTIES('auto.purge'='true');

" --hiveconf hive.merge.mapredfiles=false --hiveconf hive.auto.convert.join=true --hiveconf dfs.replication=2 --hiveconf hive.exec.compress.output=true --hiveconf hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask=true --hiveconf mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize=-1 --hiveconf hive.merge.mapfiles=false --hiveconf hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size=100000000 --hiveconf hive.stats.autogather=true
```

Error is as below

```
OK
Time taken: 1.315 seconds
OK
Time taken: 0.09 seconds
MismatchedTokenException(334!=347)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:6179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:3808)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:204)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 15:42 mismatched input '(' expecting ) near 'double' in create table statement
```

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I think I finally Figured it out seems DOUBLE with precision is not supported by Hive . But I think Kylin should take care of this while importing the jdbc metadata into the model .

Will raise an enhancement or bug in Kylin for the same .

Answer (score 0):

I installed the newest stable hive in my test env, which version is 2.3.4( Hive DDL doc says 2.2.0 support double with precision). I found hive didn't not support double with specific/user-defined precision.

e.g.

- [ERROR] create table haha(ha double 10);
- [ERROR] create table haha(ha double Precision 17);
- [ERROR] create table haha(ha double(22));
- [CORRECT] create table haha(ha double Precision);

Hive CMD:

```
hive> use ss;
OK
Time taken: 0.015 seconds
hive> create table haha(ha double 10);
FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 extraneous input '10' expecting ) near '<EOF>'
hive> create table haha(ha double Precision 17);
FAILED: ParseException line 1:38 extraneous input '17' expecting ) near '<EOF>'
hive> create table haha(ha double(22));
MismatchedTokenException(334!=347)
at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(BaseRecognizer.java:115)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.createTableStatement(HiveParser.java:6179)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:3808)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:208)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:27 mismatched input '(' expecting ) near 'double' in create table statement
hive> create table haha(ha double Precision);
OK
Time taken: 0.625 seconds
```

**So, as far as I can concerned, Hive didn't support such data type definition. It can not be resolved by kylin dev.**

If you found any mistake, please let me know. And I found below links which maybe helpful:

1. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable
2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13556